# Have other countries said what they'd do if Ethiopia recognizes Somaliland's indepedence?

Tags: secession, statehood, somalia, ethiopia, somaliland

[Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/africa/somalia-will-defend-itself-if-ethiopia-seals-illegal-port-deal-president-says-2024-02-23/):

> Feb 23, 2024
>
> Landlocked Ethiopia agreed a memorandum of understanding on Jan. 1 to lease 20 km (12 miles) of coastline in Somaliland - a territory that Somalia says it owns, even though the northern region has enjoyed effective autonomy since 1991.
>
> Ethiopia said it wants to set up a naval base there and offered possible recognition of Somaliland in exchange - prompting a defiant response from Somalia and fears the deal could further destabilise the Horn of Africa. [...]
>
> "If they come into the country, Somalia will do everything that it can to defend itself." He did not go into further detail on what action Somalia might take.

But Somalia can't even deal with Somaliland seceding, let alone if Ethiopia were to help that.

So, I guess it would be down to other countries taking a stance and pressuring Ethiopia. Have any countries said what they'd do as countermeasures if Ethiopia recognizes Somaliland's independence?

FWTW Wikipedia says that "As of 2023, Taiwan's Ministry of Foreign Affairs refers to Somaliland as a country."

Comment: All the more interesting since Somalia is the textbook definition of a failed state, so the usual logic by which a region unilaterally seceding from its host country is universally frowned upon is... obviously applicable even when said host country barely exists in the first place?